# How to select an option from dropdown while using autoMagiQ for test automation?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

Our company uses autoMagiQ for our testing our product, a banking application. I have a question on how to use it for a particular scenario. In the *create action* step, how do we let the tool select 5th option in a dropdown list every time?